# Perform pattern matching and guard at the same time

Tags: haskell

I want to perform pattern matching over a Maybe expression **and** apply a guard at once, something like:

```
myFunction :: Int -> Maybe Int  
myFunction x = --.................

let val = myFunction 333 
case val of
  Just val ??? if val > 0 ??? ->  "> 0 " ++ show val  
  Just val ??? if val == 0 ??? -> "== 0 " ++ show val
  Just val ??? if val < -5 and > -10??? -> "< -5 and > -10 " ++ show val
  _ -> "otherwise"
```

Possible?

**updated**:

How do I "chain" (if possible) this? Do I have necessarily to use `let`?

```
main = do
  Just val <- (lookup collection123 "value123"), val > 0 = ....
  -- or
  Just val <- (lookup collection123 "value123"), val == 0 = 
  -- or
  Just val <- (lookup collection123 "value123"), val < -5 and > -10 =
  -- or
  otherwise = --....
```

The error is `parse error on input ,`

Comment: It's not very clear what you're wanting to do.  Where is `val` coming from?  If there's a `Just val` coming from somewhere, where is it coming from?  You function is supposed to return a `Maybe Int`, but instead you're returning `String`, did you mean that `myFunction :: Int -> Maybe Int -> String`?

Comment: Your second use case is exactly what `PatternGuards` aims to accomplish: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pattern_guard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a normal `case` block:

```
case myFunction 333 of
    Just val | val > 0               ->  "> 0 " ++ show val  
             | val == 0              -> "== 0 " ++ show val
             | val < -5 && val > -10 -> "< -5 and > -10 " ++ show val
    _ -> "otherwise"
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question right, you could use [pattern guards](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pattern_guard) in Haskell 2010 when defining a function as follows:

```
myFunction m
    | Just val <- m, val > 0 = "> 0 " ++ show val
    | Just val <- m, val == 0 = "== 0 " ++ show val
    | Just val <- m, val < -5  && val > -10 = "< -5 and > -10 " ++ show val
    | otherwise = "otherwise"
```

Pattern guards offer a different (often more succinct) style for writing things, which can be done equivalently without using pattern guards. In case of your second example, you could do the following if you still want to use pattern guards:

```
m = Just 3 -- lookup collection123 "value123"
main  
  | Just val <- m, val > 0 = do
                  putStrLn $ "> 0 " ++ show val
  | Just val <- m, val == 0 = do 
                  putStrLn $ "== 0 " ++ show val
  | Just val <- m, val < -5 && val > -10 = do
                  putStrLn $ "< -5 and > -10 " ++ show val
  | otherwise = undefined
```

Because `main` has a type `IO()`, you need to use the `do` notation (or otherwise compose) if multiple actions are used to handle each case.

Comment: what if the functions accepts 2 arguments `myFunction m n` and returns still Maybe Int, how do I rewrite `| Just val <- ???m n???, val > 0 =...`?

Comment: You could "chain" "assignments" like | Just val1 <- m, Just val2 <- n, val1 > 0, val2 < 2 = ...   ; the grammar is like list comprehension

Comment: Updated for your second question.

Comment: thanks. but are you sure it's a valid syntax? where is "do" in "main"?

Comment: do was omitted because there is only one action per case. You can add do back like the updated version. Both are valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MultiWayIf` to handle something like this with nice syntax:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}
myFunction :: Int -> Maybe Int  
myFunction x = Just x

main = print $ 
  case myFunction 333 of
    Just val -> 
      if | val > 0  -> "> 0 " ++ show val  
         | val == 0 -> "== 0 " ++ show val
         | (val < -5 && val > -10) -> "< -5 and > -10 " ++ show val
         | otherwise -> "otherwise"
    _ -> "Nothing"
```

Comment: I prefer not to use any extensions for now.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Then you'll have to chains of `if` statements, I'll update the answer. `Pattern Guards` mentioned in the answer above also require an extension.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Nevermind! jwodder's answer is best, I think. I overlooked that.